# Webpack bundle build crashing my website everytime a user uploads an image

Tags: node.js, express, webpack, multer

I have a website where people can upload images, **it used to be working just fine for like 2 weeks** but now, everytime an image is uploaded, the whole website is crashing. The log just shows this after some images are uploaded:

```
webpack building...
ℹ ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /index.html
ℹ ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /robots.txt
ℹ ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /index.html
webpack built d08e4556b6dc12db2a92 in 2727313ms
```

From what I have experimented, it looks like the issue is with

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
      from: helpers.root('client/public')
    }])
```

If I remove this from the webpack config, the website is working and people can upload images, but well, no one can see these images, as they won't get in the `dist` folder... I'm not sure if that's how you upload images correctly with express/webpack: I put them somewhere in the public folder of my app with `multer` and then webpack picks them up with this plugin.

I have not changed anything in the code of the upload. It stopped working for some reason. Maybe a reboot caused this issue? I'm using an EC2 instance. I really can't figure out what's the matter.

Has anyone ever experienced something similar?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the end, I changed my approach.

I now upload the images to S3 and do not store them in the server anymore, works fine. As for the original issue, never found a solution, but that new approach is fine with me.